# How to add vertical lines and annotation to survival plot with risk table (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, intercept, geom-vline

I want to have a survival plot with a risk table with a vertical line at 12 months and 36 months. Initially I was able to go this

```
figure1$plot + geom_vline(xintercept = 12) + geom_vline(intercept = 36)
```

However when I want to add the risk table as follows

```
figure1$plot + figure1$table + geom_vline(xintercept = 12) + geom_vline(intercept = 36)
```

I get the error message of "Don't know how to add figure1$table to a plot"

Any recs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear - it is unclear what you have tried, which package you used, etc..

I am guessing you are using `survminer` and are trying to modify the plot object and plot it together with the risk table. The way you would do this is shown in the reproducible example below:

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE) 
p1$plot <- p1$plot + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 250) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 360)
p1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>